# How to test MSN Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, msn

A client is seeing bugs on their website using MSN Explorer. I can't reproduce those bugs with IE7 or any other browser, and I can't use MSN Explorer, because it requires a subscription to MSN.

- What is MSN Explorer based on? I assumed it was exactly the same as IE7 with a different interface, from wikipedia and the user-agent string.
- Is there any way to test it? I can't find any browser screenshot sites that have MSN.
- Is there any possibility it's just different enough from IE7 to have its own bugs, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: I've still been unable to find the bug, and I'm thinking that MSN Explorer has some differences from any IE version. But thanks for the help - I've accepted the most useful post as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is MSN Explorer based on?

From the install page [here](http://explorer.msn.com/install.htm), there is this note at the bottom:

> **Note**: this version of MSN contains Internet Explorer 5.5

Hopefully that helps.  I can't use MSN explorer either, so there is no guarantee that this information is correct.

> **Edit**: The IE 5.5 information is corroborated by the warning I got when
> trying to access this site from Linux:
> http://explorer.msn.com/langwarn.htm?prompt=1

#### Is there any way to test it?

Based on the info above, if you can find a screenshot site that supports IE 5.5, I would imagine the rendering should match MSN explorer.

#### Is there any possibility it's just different enough from IE7 to have its own bugs, or should I look elsewhere?

Oh, it's incredibly possible.  If you can't get a version of IE 5.5, at the very *least*, I would suggest grabbing a copy of IE 6.  Microsoft supports [Virtual PC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) that come installed with IE 6 that you could use to test.

Comment: IE 7: bad. IE 6: worse. IE 5: my skin just crawled off me.

Comment: Agreed.  If it really is using IE 5.5 at its core then I do not envy the agony that Alex will endure if the customer insists on sticking with MSN.

Comment: Wow - the odd thing is that the site is using PNG transparent images, and those appear fine in the screenshot the client has sent me. In IE 5.5 those PNGs look distinctly wrong - maybe MSN uses whatever version of IE installed by default on the OS? Starting with IE5.5 if there's nothing better?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to support the idea that its the same rendering engine as IE 5.5.  Looking at the Trident wikipedia page, it looks like transparent PNG wasn't added to IE until whatever version of Trident shipped with IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were looking for browser screenshots pages before, so you may have come across this, but [IE NetRenderer](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/) provides a web-based interface to preview your page in IE 5.5 through IE 8. Since it sounds like MSN is based on 5.5 maybe that will be useful. Most of my web development takes place on a Mac, so it's been a convenient tool.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into installing the [Multiple IE installation package](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) from TredoSoft. The installation contains IE3 IE4.01 IE5 IE5.5 and IE6.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) allows you to view your sites in IE 5.5 - 8.